# How do I get the new "Music" section of the market to show up?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo

It appears Google has updated the market application. Including documentation in the new Google Music application for a link to `/music` in the market. The link does nothing on my phone except take me to the home screen of the market though. I'm super excited for this new feature and would like to use it now. Is there a way to force the market to update or anything? I'm using stock 2.2 Froyo on T-Mobile Defy (rooted)

Comment: Indications are that you just have to wait as it rolls out: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/16/google-music-support-is-rolling-out-to-the-android-market-now-no-update-necessary/

Comment: Actually after seeing the dim prospects of Google Music (come on, no The Used?) I've decided to make due with Spotify Premium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this, and it works.  Go into `Settings > Applications > Manage applications > All > Market`  then clear data, and cache.  I had to reboot the phone after.  But once it reboots, go into the Market, and the music section should be there.

Comment: Clearing the data also clears the cache.

Comment: that worked perfectly :)